# Unable to run the smart contract due to error - false Transaction mined but execution failed

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I am new to Solidity and trying to write a smart contract to trade carbon credits.
However, I am getting error as below:

```
transact to CarbonCreditTrade.buyCarbonCredits pending ... 
transact to CarbonCreditTrade.buyCarbonCredits errored: VM error: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Reason provided by the contract: "Insufficient token for desired number of credits".
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

My smart contract is as below and I am trying to buy 10 carbon credits:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.8.2 <0.9.0;

/**
 * @title Storage
 * @dev Store & retrieve value in a variable
 * @custom:dev-run-script ./scripts/deploy_with_ethers.ts
 */
contract CarbonCreditTrade {

    address payable public buyer;
    address payable public seller;
    uint public carbonCreditsAvailable;
    uint public rewardPointsAwarded;
    uint public creditPrice;

    constructor(uint256 _creditPrice) payable{
        seller = payable(msg.sender);
        carbonCreditsAvailable = 10000; //set the initial number of carbon credits available
        creditPrice = _creditPrice;
    }

    function buyCarbonCredits(uint _creditsToBuy) external payable{
        require(msg.sender != seller, "seller cannot buy CC");
        require(msg.sender != buyer, "buyer cannot be same as seller");
        require(_creditsToBuy <= carbonCreditsAvailable, "insufficient carbon credits available");

        uint256 totalCost = _creditsToBuy * creditPrice; //set the cost of each carboncredit

        require(msg.value >= totalCost,"Insufficient token for desired number of credits");

        buyer = payable(msg.sender);
        carbonCreditsAvailable -= _creditsToBuy;
        rewardPointsAwarded += _creditsToBuy / 10;
      
        if(msg.value > totalCost)      {
            uint refundAmount = msg.value - totalCost;
            payable(buyer).transfer(refundAmount);
        }
    }

    function getRewardPointsAwarded() external view returns (uint){
        return rewardPointsAwarded;
    }

}
```

Appreciate any help please

Comment: Clearly you're using a `msg.value` too low. The contract is fine, the problem must be in the way you send the transaction.

Comment: Thanks @0xSanson...that could possibly be an issue though I cannot figure out why. When I pass 0 carbon credits to buy it works fine. Any value more than that I get this error. Though I see carbon credits available as 10000. I am passing creditPrice as 1.Can you please help on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Oops/...I had "msg.value <= totalCost" the wrong way!!....Thanks @0xSanson for your help!